# Run separate macros depending on checkbox value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to call a different macro depending on whether my checkbox (form control) is checked (true) or not (false).

Any idea on the syntax?

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply talking about an if statement?

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    RunSomeSub
Else
    RunSomeOtherSub
End IF
```

Comment: Hi MattewD. Thanks for that. Yes I would think so, but not really sure where to paste that and what to prefix it with? (private sub etc). Apologies but I have a very basic and patchy knowledge of VBA! Thank you

Comment: Sorry I've managed to get it now. Thanks for your suggestion any how